# Reapplying for a Schengen visa

Tags: schengen

I applied for a short stay Schengen visa with multiple entries from 21st of June till 21st of September. I booked holidays to go to Spain and France. The Spanish embassy only gave me the visa for 1 month and one entry. Now the visa expires the 20th of July.

The problem is that I booked my tickets to go to Spain for a week from the 21st of June and to France from the 17th of July till the 20th of July (the day that the visa expires), but I'm only allowed one entry. Is it possible to reapply from the French embassy to be able to enter France even though the old visa hasn't expired yet?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to apply for a new visa before the first one expires but they would probably refuse to issue a new visa overlapping the first one. In your case, I think the recommended course of action is to apply for a new visa after returning to your country of residence (i.e. at the beginning of July, between the two trips). The time is short but if the application is complete it should be OK.